# calculate with a php variable and put it in css

Tags: html, css, width, php

I am working on a webshop and it has some images for the products.
like this:
[image: old]
but i want it like this:
dont mind the overflow i am working on a scrollbar, and i know how to fix this
[image: new]
obviously i know i can do this with css!
but the width needs to be calculated from the amout of images.
one image is 68px wide, so if there are 12 images the width needs to be 816px.

this is some code I experimented with:
(only the first `<ul>` tag)

```
<ul class = "listimages" style="width:<?php Echo $this->getGalleryImages() * 68;?>;">


 <?php $i = 1; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#fancy-zoom-gallery-image-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="fancy-zoom-gallery-link" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($this->getThumbWidth(), $this->getThumbHeight()); ?>" width="<?php echo $this->getThumbWidth(); ?>" height="<?php echo $this->getThumbHeight(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
        </li>
    <?php ++$i; endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

what is the best way to do this?
i dont have alot of experience with php but i know some basics.

**solution:**
`<ul class = "listimages" style="width:<?php echo count($this->getGalleryImages()) * 68 ?>px;">`

thanks Francios B for this answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `len` you may count number of images to be displayed.

```
<ul class = "listimages" style="width:<?= count($this->getGalleryImages()) * 86 ?>px;">
```

Comment: sadly this did not work, i think you meant `<?php len(` instead of `<?= len(` but when i tried that it still did not show anything after the len code. then i replaced len with echo and it showed the rest again but without anything changed.

Comment: `<?php Echo "xxx"; ?>` is equal to `<?= "xxx"?>`. Shorter form to echo stuffs.

Comment: try with `count` instead of `len`.

Comment: when i used `len` the rest of the page would be empty(after the len code), but now that i used `count` it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: oh wait it did work but we forgot about the `px` behind `width:816`1

Comment: sure. `px` is needed!